# How to run rails 2 project with rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have an old rails project.
in environment.rb:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

& I wanna run it with rails -v=2.3.8

```
I use RVM
    => ree-1.8.7-2011.12 [ i686 ]
my ruby -v
    ruby 1.8.7
my rails -v
    Rails 2.3.8
```

my gem list:

> ```
> actionmailer (2.3.8)
> actionpack (2.3.8)
> activerecord (2.3.8)
> activerecord-postgresql-adapter (0.0.1)
> activeresource (2.3.8)
> activesupport (2.3.8)
> bundler (1.3.4, 1.0.21)
> fastercsv (1.5.5)
> geokit (1.5.0)
> htmlentities (4.2.4)
> i18n (0.6.1)
> mime-types (1.19)
> multi_json (1.5.0)
> pg (0.14.1)
> rack (1.1.3)
> rails (2.3.8)
> rake (10.0.3, 0.8.7)
> rest-client (1.6.7)
> rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
> rvm (1.11.3.6)
> ```

& when I try to run -> `ruby script/server`
I get this msg -> "Could not find activesupport-3.2.10 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems."

If I run 'bundle install' my rails version will be updated to Rails 3.2.10
& then, again, if I try to run -> ruby script/server -> I get this msg -> "Missing the Rails 2.3.8 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.8 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed."

I do what it says :) -> `gem install -v=2.3.8 rails`
but, again I get the same msg ->

> "Missing the Rails 2.3.8 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.8 rails`,
>   update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the
>   Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION
>   to use the latest version installed."

Thank you.

Comment: Is that the gem list you get when you execute bundle install or is it your Gemfile

Comment: After "bundle install" I have a different gem list But, I made a copy (rvm gemset copy yyy6@xxx yyy@xxx_C). So, I'm trying both:) gem list I exposed in my question & other "gem list" that I have after "bundle install"

Answer (score 0):

Try running everything with `bundle exec`:

`bundle exec ruby script/server`

Also in your Gemfile, set the rails version:

`gem 'rails', '2.3.8'`

That way `bundle install` won't try to upgrade you.

Comment: Thank you :) I tried "bundle exec ruby script/server" & I get this msg->"Could not find activesupport-3.2.10 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems." Also, I wrote it(config.gem 'rails', :version => '2.3.8') in my environment.rb

Comment: Do you have a Gemfile and did you set gem 'rails', '2.3.8' in it?

Comment: There is no Gemfile in my rails 2 project. But, there is environment.rb. They are the same, right? I'm kinda new to rails 2 :)